# How to compile AD9834 kernel driver

Tags: linux-device-driver, iio

I have an AD9834 (it's a Direct Digital Synthesis chip) evaluation board that I'd like to connect to my Raspberry PI. It uses an SPI interface. While I could just drive the SPI interface directly from Python, etc. I'd prefer to use the [Linux kernel driver](https://wiki.analog.com/resources/tools-software/linux-drivers/iio-dds/ad9834) that Analog Devices has already written.

The driver is an IIO subsystem driver. The compilation instructions mention the standard procedure of `make menuconfig` and choosing the driver for compilation. Before that however, the instructions talk about source code configuration for slave-select lines etc. The instructions state that, "For compile time configuration, it’s common Linux practice to keep board- and application-specific configuration out of the main driver file, instead putting it into the board support file." I have no experience with this and haven't found any information about a, "board support file" other than Board Support Packages which the Raspberry Pi doesn't (?) use.

How should I apply these board support source modifications to the Raspberry Pi's Linux kernel?

Comment: Please don't cross-post the same question on multiple SE sites. As far as I can tell, this is on-topic on both RPiSE and here, but it should only be on one at a time.

Comment: So go ahead and delete it from there right away? I think people in the Raspberry Pi forum may not have this type of knowledge.

Comment: Deleting it from either site is fine. If the one you leave up doesn't get any answers after a while, then you can try the other site.

Comment: Yeah. That's how I came here. I posted the other one over a month ago. Deleted.

Comment: Thanks. On to your question - I unfortunately don't have an answer for you. The RPi uses a [device tree](http://elinux.org/Device_Tree_Reference) rather than board files, and your [driver's help page](https://wiki.analog.com/resources/tools-software/linux-drivers/iio-dds/ad9834) hasn't been updated to address device tree usage. The two approaches are incompatible. I think your best bet is to ask a question in [Analog's Linux software forum](https://ez.analog.com/community/linux-device-drivers/linux-software-drivers).

Comment: I followed your suggestion and got an answer: [Analog Devices will add Device Tree support](https://ez.analog.com/message/315809?commentID=315809)! Care to add an answer about how RPi uses Device Tree and it's best to contact the driver maintainer?

Comment: Best strategy here is to push them to push the driver in upstream.